# What is the size of the exterior angle of a regular octagon?

Tags: geometry

Can't really remember the rules for exterior and interior angles and don't really know what a "regular octagon" is.

Any help is appreciated thanks!

Comment: [regular polygon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_polygon)

Comment: You couldn't do a Google search for "regular octagon"?  Really?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A regular $n$-gon are polygons with each side and internal angle being the same (e.g., equilateral triangles for $n = 3$, squares for $n = 4$, etc.). Each one has an interior angle of $\frac{180(n-2)}{n}$ degrees (e.g., as shown in the [Angles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_polygon#Angles) section of Wikipedia's "Regular polygon" article). Thus, for regular octagons, $n = 8$, so each interior angle is $\frac{180 \times 6}{8} = 135^{o}$, and thus each exterior angle is $180^{o} - 135^{o} = 45^{o}$.

Answer (score 1):

This diagram of a regular octagon should help:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The sum of the angles of an $n$-gon is $180(n - 2)$. 
Plugging $n = 8$ here, we obtain $180 × 6 = 1080^\circ.$ Since the polygon is regular, an interior angle measures $\frac{1080}{8} = 135^\circ $. Since the exterior and interior angles of any polygon are supplementary, the exterior angle is then $180 - 135 = 45^\circ $

Answer (score 0):

The regular octegon is a polygon with $8$ Equal sides  .The interior angle is $135$ degrees.

The complement of that which is  $180-135=45$ degrees is considered as the exterior angle.